# Unit testing $urlRouterProvider.otherwise in provider config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

So i've got my code:

```
(function (ng) {
    ng.module('myModuleName')
        .provider('myProviderName', ['importedThing', function (importedThing) {
            //lots of cool stuff happens in here
            }];
        }])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'importedThing', 'myProviderNameProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, importedThing, myProvider) {
            window.stateProvider = $stateProvider;

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
                $location.path("/pages");
            });
        }]);
}(angular));
```

I need to unit test this line for code coverage:

```
$location.path("/" + myProvider.coolString);
```

But I can't figure out how. I've seen several people do it with controllers, but not with providers.

I've got the unit test set up like:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.module('dsLocale', function () { }).config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
        $urp = $urlRouterProvider;
        $urp.deferIntercept();
    });
});

//Lines are commented to represent random stuff I've tried already.
it('should call otherwise', function () {
    //$urp.otherwise('/otherwise');
    //$location.path("/lastrule");
    console.log($location.path());
    //local.$emit("$locationChangeSuccess");
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

I feel like it should be as easy as just changing $location.Path to something that doesn't exist, so UIRouter can do it's thing but it doesn't appear to be that easy. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just had the same problem. I wanted to test the otherwise functionality, but did not how, i figured out a way and this worked for me.

I am setting the path with location.path, firing the $locationChangeSuccess event and then it works

```
it('redirects to otherwise page after locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        location.path('/nonExistentPath');
        rootScope.$emit("$locationChangeSuccess");
        expect(location.path()).toBe("/");
    });
```

without the event, the path is the of course /nonExistentPath

--
this is my full test file. Be aware, i am using browserify and the file maybe looks a little different than yours

```
    'use strict';

require('../../../app');

var objectToTest = 'CoreRouterConfig';

describe(objectToTest, function () {
    var rootScope,
        state,
        location;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('core'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $state, $location) {
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        state = $state;
        location = $location;
    }));

    it('should respond home state', function() {
        expect(state.href('home')).toEqual('#/');
    });

    it('init path is correct', function() {
        rootScope.$emit("$locationChangeSuccess");
        expect(location.path()).toBe("/");
    });

    it('redirects to otherwise page after locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        location.path('/nonExistentPath');
        rootScope.$emit("$locationChangeSuccess");
        expect(location.path()).toBe("/");
    });

    it('does not redirect to otherwise page without locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        location.path('/nonExistentPath');
        expect(location.path()).toBe("/nonExistentPath");
    });
});
```